# How to check page is cart page or not in Shopify

Tags: shopify, cart, shopping-cart, shopify-api

How can I check if the current page is the cart page or not in front side?

I try to find page type using `ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.pageType`. This works for all pages (like product and collection page) but doesn't work for cart page.

If you have any idea, please give answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
add this condition

{% if template == 'cart' %}
//your code here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This condition work in liquid file but i want to check condition in app, so have any idea please give the answer.

Comment: which app @dishaLashkari ? 
custom app ?
or public app ?

Comment: i make public app.....